# Is there an efficient way to accumulate values from a nested instance in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, instance

I have an instance that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "cgx", 
    "capacity": 1000000000, 
    "chunks": [
        {
            "prs": [
                {
                    "segs": [
                        {
                            "node_id": "server-0",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "prs": [
                {
                    "segs": [
                        {
                            "node_id": "server-2",
                        }
                    ]
                },
               {
                    "segs": [
                        {
                            "node_id": "server-3",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "health": "healthy", 
    "status": "ok"
}
```

each 'chunk' in the chunks array is a Chunk instance, each 'pr' in the prs array is a Pr instance, each 'seg' in the segs array is a Seg instance

I want to traverse the instance and accumulate a set of 'node_id' values from all of the instance. I did it in the following way:

```
 def setDistinctElements(self, result):
            elements = []
            for chunk in getattr(result, 'chunks'):
                for pr in getattr(chunk, 'prs'):
                    for seg in getattr(pRaid, 'segs'):
                        elements.append(getattr(seg, 'node_id'))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it instead of looping 3 times? Each such instance can have a lot of 'chunks', 'prs' and 'segs' instances nested in it.

Comment: Does the provided code work? If it does, what output do you get? along with what's desired?

Comment: Yes it works, I will get a list: ['server-0', 'server-1', 'server-2']. I am asking if there is a more efficient way to achieve this result,

Comment: Looping is *not* inefficient for this problem, and anyway `getattr` is O(1).

Comment: I am aware it is not efficient, hence the question, I have a filling it can be done with map and raduce in a more elegant way.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog said that your solution was not **in**efficient. That is, it's fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "instance"? That is a very generic term. An instance **of what**?

Comment: If that's not what your data actually looks like, update your question to show the actual data. Otherwise you're going to get less helpful answers.

Comment: An instance of an object that I defined with these attributes: _id, capacity, chunks, health, and status, when each element of the chunks attribute is a chunk instance of an object that I defined with the attribute prs, when each element of the prs attribute is an instance of an object pr that I defined with the attribute segs, when each element of the segs attribute is an instance of an object seg that I defined with the attribute node_id. And I want a list of all the values of the nested attribute 'node_id'.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run your code so made a similar one.
and to run it faster I convert the json to string and mess with it to get what I need. and it's almost X2 faster [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VYkS.png)

```
lst = []
for row in a.replace('[','').replace(' ','').replace('{','').replace('\n','').replace(']','').replace('}','').replace('"','').sp
lit(','):
if "node_id" in row:
      lst.append(row.split(':')[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator to traverse a structure of any depth:

```
data = {'_id': 'cgx', 'capacity': 1000000000, 'chunks': [{'prs': [{'segs': [{'node_id': 'server-0'}]}]}, {'prs': [{'segs': [{'node_id': 'server-2'}]}, {'segs': [{'node_id': 'server-3'}]}]}], 'health': 'healthy', 'status': 'ok'}

def get_nodes(d):
  for a, b in d.items():
    if a == 'node_id':
      yield b
    elif isinstance(b, dict):
      yield from get_nodes(b)
    elif isinstance(b, list):
      for c in b:
        yield from get_nodes(c)

print(list(get_nodes(data)))
```

Output:

```
['server-0', 'server-2', 'server-3']
```